# Method to compute $\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{(\log(\frac{xy}{2}))^2 (x^2+y^2) }{(x^2-y^2)^{2}}\,dx \,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Can anybody give a hint, how to compute the integral analytically
$$
\int_{\sqrt{\,{2}\,}}^{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{\,{2}\,}}
\log^{2}\left(xy \over 2\right)\,
{x^{2} + y^{2} \over \left(\,{x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\right)^{2}}
\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$
Please, I am not looking for computer assisted proofs.

Comment: Did you try say substitution $u=x^2+y^2,\,v=x^2-y^2$?

Comment: I am aware of the convergence of the integral, but the above substitution does not make life simple.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if the integrals are in fact interchangeable using Fubini/Tonelli's theorem. Note that the integrand is positive everywhere, so that to verify that $f$ is integrable:
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}}f^{+}  = \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}}\max(f, 0) \leq\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}}|f|<\infty
$$
The only case when integrand doesn't exist is $x=y=\sqrt{2}$. Taking the upper bound on $X$ and $Y$ we get
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}}f^{+}<\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}}\frac{(\log 2 )^2}{9}<\infty
$$
The last function is integrable because it is defined on a compact set. So the requirement of Fubini's theorem is fulfilled and integrals are exchangeable. Now you can use the substitution trick recommended by @AlexeyBurdin.